# How to set a value from database in asp.net at the placeholder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net project. Now the thing is that I have to place something at the placeholder after fetching it from database. The problem I am facing is that it's not been placed at the place holder. I have attached the codes. Kindly help.

```
<div class="form" >
          Recovery Email
            <input type="text" class ="form-control" placeholder= <asp:placeholder id = "DisID" runat ="server"/> <br />
```

C# Code

```
public void userName()
{
        String name = "";

        SqlCommand thisCommand = cn.CreateCommand();
        thisCommand.CommandText = "Select * from person;";

        cn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            name = reader.GetString(0);
        }

        DisID.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(name));
}
```

Comment: The sql statment is working fine.

Comment: You cannot use a server side control as `<asp:placeholder>` like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your real intention is to set `placeholder` attribute of `<input>` element server-side, then you can convert the element to a server-side control:

```
<input id="myinput" runat="server" type="text" class ="form-control" placeholder="" />
```

then in code-behind use `Attributes` property:

```
public void userName()
{
     String name = "";

     SqlCommand thisCommand = cn.CreateCommand();
     thisCommand.CommandText = "Select * from person;";

     cn.Open();

     SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();

     while (reader.Read())
     {
        name = reader.GetString(0);
     }

     myinput.Attributes["placeholder"] = name;
}
```

Comment: @AliSajid Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done sir but can you also tell me one other thing that how can I set checkboxes through this?

Comment: @AliSajid It is generally discouraged to answer to questions through comments in SO. You can try posting a new question.